# How to force Photos to release space for an iCloud backed library?

Tags: mac, icloud, catalina, photos

I have migrated my 200 gigabyte Photos library to iCloud on my Mac.  Works very well.

I then created a new, empty library on the Mac and let Photos copy the whole iCloud contents locally on the Mac.  Now I need the space locally, so I would like Photos to undo the local copying only leaving the preview image locally and release say 150 Gb of the 200.   Clicking the "Optimize Mac-storage" radio button in preferences (and waiting days while having About this Mac -> System report -> Storage administration open) does not do this.

Is there a way to trigger this process?  Is the only way to delete my current library, create a new empty library on the Mac, and let it populate?

Comment: I'd consider this 'playing with fire' & would just buy an external disk as secure long-term storage instead. […or two, or indeed an entire off-site backup solution, iCloud is **not** a backup solution]

Comment: I have a backup elsewhere.  I just want to go back to the "do not store everything on this machine" model.